# REGEX extract string between quotes but after a specified string

Tags: regex, string, etl

how can I extract a string between quotes which is coming after a specified string.

example string:

> name familyname "martin" age year "25" owner of "mercedes"

the regex: `\"(.*?)\"` 
is giving me: "martin" 
but I want the word between quotes after the word owner or age

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like there are always two words followed by the variable: `\w+\s\w+\s\"(.*?)\"` right?

Answer (score 0):

This regex with **capture in the first match** whatever is between quotes after the word 'age' and i**n the second match** what is between quotes after 'owner' for this kind of text:

*name familyname "martin" age year "25" owner of "mercedes"*

```
/^.* age .*\"(.*)\" owner .*\"(.*)\"$/
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex below will capture the words "age" or "owner" in capture group 1 and what's  between quotes in capture group 2.

```
\b(age|owner)\b[^"]+"([^"]*)"
```

Regex101 test [here](https://regex101.com/r/4xTChk/2)